# Fatal error: Class 'WP_Scripts' not found in wp-includes\functions.wp-scripts.php

Tags: wordpress, fatal-error

I have to developed the new wordpress site in my localhost xammp server.

the following fatal error is shown to me Fatal error: Class 'WP_Scripts' not found in wp-includes\functions.wp-scripts.php on line 23.

how to solve this issue, pls anyone help for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-install wordpress again, as somefiles are missing thats why it showing this error.

Do below steps:

- Copy your downloaded wordpress repository and paste it again in xamp
  server
- setup wordpress again
- conect with db by adding db configuration

then your issue get resolved

Answer (score 0):

Put this file in wp-includes folder

```
class.wp-scripts.php
```

Note: you can find this file from any new wp-setup.